# Read specific HTTP header value from key/value collection in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read two header values from an HTTP method and have a few gaps in my C# knowledge. I can see a `Results View` in the locals when debugging and I can also see it is a `System.Collections.Generic` but I don't know how to access this list to obtain my two values.

**Here is my Azure Function App code:**

```
[FunctionName("Tenant")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Tenant/{DomainName}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string DomainName, [Inject(typeof(ITableOps))]ITableOps _tableOps, TraceWriter log)
{
    var headers = req.Headers;
    var settings = _tableOps.GetTenantSettingsAsync(DomainName);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, settings.Result);
}
```

[image: Results View]

From this key/value list I'd like to get the key named `apikey` and `domainName` and I've tried all sorts of strange ways to do this:

```
 headers.ToList()[0]
```

or

```
var key = headers.Where(x => x.Key == "apikey")
```

Given the second example, `key` ends up being another list:

[image: List]

I've seen quite a few examples on using foreach loops but in my case I thought I could use a lambda to extract the value since I'm expecting two very specific key names. I realize this is easy to obtain but I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Headers` is a `HttpRequestHeaders` class, that class has a [`TryGetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues) function that is for this exact situation.

```
[FunctionName("Tenant")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Tenant/{DomainName}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string DomainName, [Inject(typeof(ITableOps))]ITableOps _tableOps, TraceWriter log)
{
    var headers = req.Headers;
    if(!headers.TryGetValues("apiKey", out var apiKeys) ||
       !headers.TryGetValues("domain", out var domains))
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
    var apiKey = apiKeys.First();
    var domain = domains.First();

    //Do something with apiKey and domain here.

    var settings = _tableOps.GetTenantSettingsAsync(DomainName);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, settings.Result);
}
```

There also is a `GetValues` function that could be used like

```
[FunctionName("Tenant")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Tenant/{DomainName}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string DomainName, [Inject(typeof(ITableOps))]ITableOps _tableOps, TraceWriter log)
{
    var headers = req.Headers;
    var apiKey = headers.GetValues("apiKey").First();
    var domain = headers.GetValues("domain").First();

    //Do something with apiKey and domain here.

    var settings = _tableOps.GetTenantSettingsAsync(DomainName);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, settings.Result);
}
```

However `GetValues` will throw a `InvalidOperationException` if the header was not sent with the request so doing a `TryGetValues` would be faster due to no exception overhead.

The `HttpRequestHeaders` is a kind of like a `Dictionary<string, List<string>` internally so a dictionary lookup would be the preferred way to do it.

Comment: Perfect. Works well and I now understand the concept.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to get one item at the time is to use `FirstOrDefault()` which returns the first element from the list that matches your expression. If no elements exist it will return null.

```
var key = headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "apikey");
```

To get both keys

```
var yourKeys = new List<string>{"apikey", "domainName"};
headers.Where(x => yourKeys.Contains(x.Key)).ToList();
```